# how to fill a dropdown list from a listGrid

Tags: smartgwt, smartclient

I have a dropdown list that should contain object types, and I have a listGrid which contains all types with icones. 
Can i transfer the elements of this listGrid to the dropdown list? 
the getData() is it a good idea ?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is solved! 
you must use the optionDataSource attribute and specify the same DataSource as the list: